# buenas tardes, quisiera saber como puedo escribir una funcion que pase de minutos a segundos. Muchas gracias

Tags: javascript, funciones

He intentado de todo y no me sale agradeceria mucho su apollo

```
function minutosASegundos(minutos) {
      // Escribir una funcion que reciba un entero (minutos)
      // y retorne la cantidad de segundos
      // ej:
      // minutosASegundos(5) => 300
      // minutosASegundos(3) => 180
      // Tu código aca:
    }
```

Comment: Con escribir la funcion no basta, debes poner aquello que haz intentado en codigo, en pocas palabras nos estas pidiendo que resolvamos tu ejercicio sin siquiera haberlo intentado, o por lo menos, no nos muestras de que forma lo haz intentado, este no es un foro de preguntas, se resuelven dudas puntuales en base a codigo que ya tengas o errores que poseas, porfavor leer [ask].

Comment: 6 cosas: 1. Título = Idea general. 2. Cuerpo del mensaje = detalles. 3. Coloca todo lo que has intentado, los intentos aumentan el % de conseguir una respuesta. 4. Apollo -> Apoyo. 5. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 6. Toma estos tutoriales: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javascriptya/ y https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript Saludos.

Comment: es facil lo que debes hacer multiplicar minutos * 60

Comment: @fredyfx pero que excelente informacion!, voy a copiarme tu comentario y con tu permiso depronto use esos links en algun momento tienen informacion valiosa.

Comment: Los tutoriales de `programaciónYa` son bien directos y sencillos de entender, altamente recomendables :D Mozilla aporta con todos los detalles pues es documentación. Y el enlace de las recomendaciones, es efecto de llevar años por estos lares.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Espero te sirva, multiplica el número que recibes como arg (un entero) por 60

```
const minToSec = (min) => {
 let mainSec = 60;
 return min * mainSec;
}

console.log(minToSec(2))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por el apollo, bendiciones

Comment: De nada bro, sigue dándole al código! 

Comment: @Andrey Eso no es un apoyo, es hacer tu ejercicio. Te ha dado el pescado pero no has aprendido a pescar.

Comment: disculpe bro soy nuevo en este sitio apenas me acobo de registrar, no sabia como era

Comment: No bro @Andrey no tienes porque disculparte. Eres libre de hacer lo que quieras con los feedbacks que recibas, sigue así y estudia la respuesta dada 

Comment: muchas gracias por el apollo bro @ricardoleivasikic y si claro la estoy estudiando y vi algunos de mis errores 